Visualising presence/absence data over 10 years
I'm trying to create some for of graph to present the presence and absence of individuals over a ten year span but I'm struggling to find the right code.
My data is in this kind of format:
(With the years repeated 2013 to 2022 and there's around 100 individuals all with the presence data)



Year
Individual
Presence




2013
LM2
1


2014
LM2
1


2015
LM2
0



Would anyone be able to help with the type of code I could use to plot a large presence/absence graph?
I've tried using ggplot2, but I'm a novice so not too sure what to put into the code.

Welcome to SO! This sounds more like a data viz than a coding question. You might try with a heat map, e.g. ggplot(dat, aes(factor(Year), Individual, fill = factor(Presence))) + geom_tile().

Thank you! Yes that's exactly what I want. Is there a way of putting all the 2013 individuals first on the graph. At the moment it's ordered alphabetically on the y axis for the individuals but would be nice to see all the individuals that were present in 2013 first, then 2014 and so on, and see how that's dispersed over time.

As I already mentioned in my comment, you might use a heat map to visualize your data. To order by the year of first appearance you can add a column containing the minimum year with Presence == 1, then use reorder to convert to a factor with the levels ordered according the year of first appearance.
Note: To make the example data more realistic I added two more individuals.
dat <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Year = c(2013L, 2014L, 2015L),
  Individual = c("LM2", "LM2", "LM2", "LM1", "LM1", "LM1", "LM3", "LM3", "LM3"),
  Presence = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0, 1, 0)
)

library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

dat |>
  mutate(
    year_first = min(Year[Presence == 1]), .by = Individual
  ) |>
  mutate(
    Individual = reorder(Individual, year_first)
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(factor(Year), Individual, fill = factor(Presence))) +
  geom_tile()


